# Unreal Engine 4.26: How to serialize and load the array of custom UObjects (TArray<UObject*>) in C++?

Tags: c++, unreal-4, unreal, objects, serialization

I have a UProperty in struct which is a TArray<UCoverInfo*> where UCoverInfo is inherited from UObject:

```
UPROPERTY(Instanced, EditInstanceOnly, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "CoverPoints")
        TArray<UCoverInfo*> HalfBodyCoverPoints;
```

I found that when I save map and then reload it, all elements of this array lost their data and get the default values (for i.e. FVector::ZeroVector for FVector fields). And I need to generate this points again. And I will lost everything after the next map reload.

So, how to correctly save and load this UPROPERTY? I need an example of serialization functions for save and load at C++.

Comment: I see you have an array of pointers. Could raise a couple of issues, if they are constructed with `new` they could be garbage collected by Unreal, and if they are referenced in another container then that will not be reflected in your save/load.